# Chrome dev tools: finding the source of an event in the performance analysis tool?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use the performance analyzer in the Chrome dev tools to find the source of a performance problem in my Javascript code.

From the analysis, it's very clear that the performance problem comes from repeated rendering operations triggered by `mousemove` events (I've attached a screenshot that shows this).

My problem is: how do I find the **source** of these `mousemove` events? Which HTML element(s) are they originating from? I didn't register ANY handlers for mouse events in my code at all, so it must be some framework I'm using, but I have no idea how to find out which one...

[image]

Comment: I guess you'll have to add a listener manually in console e.g. window.addEventListener('mouseout', console.log)

Comment: @wOxxOm: that code registers a listener that fires for every element of the page on that particular event... how is that supposed to help me? I need to find out which element is generating a particular event, or at least find out the list of elements where that particular event is already registered... I don't see how adding NEW listeners is of any use?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Looking at your screenshot again, I see the problem is **not** the mouseout event because it's `self` time is negligible 1ms. The problem is the `Layout` update, which you can inspect by clicking that block in the chart, then switch to `Summary` panel at the bottom of devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm: yes, you are right, by looking at the layout summary you can find out which piece of code started it, which is useful. However, it still doesn't answer the original question of "which element generated that `mousemove` event"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome dev tools you can set an event listener to mouseout events. That should help you find out which function triggers this event. [image: dev tools]

Edit: I created a basic "click" event in one of my angular components and I see the event when I unfold 1000 levels. So it should be hidden somewhere inside, but it's not pretty. I would go the route of setting a breakpoint and checking this directly. In my screenshot you can see that the click event originally came from the input.component.ts file.

[image: levels of performance]

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't answer the question but it is helpful. Will mark as correct answer if nobody can come up with a proper way to find out the origin of an event in the performance analysis tool (why this isn't a default functionality in the dev tools I don't understand, seems obvious to me that if you have an event that generates overhead you would want to track down the source... weird)

Comment: added an example on how to see where this can be seen in the performance tab. It is there, it's just not nice to find. like at all :D